# Why some terminals return 4294967295 istead of 1000 for `cat /proc/self/loginuid`?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, systemd, shared-library

This question is first arise when I tried to launch great [`xsession-manager` application](https://github.com/nlpsuge/xsession-manager) on my fresh default Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2 LTS system.  Surprisingly it does not start using default MATE Terminal. So I have reported [an issue](https://github.com/nlpsuge/xsession-manager/issues/22).

Currently I see the following - some terminals wrongly react on `cat /proc/self/loginuid` and `logname` commands.

My user has name *mate*, he is only one human user on this system:

```
$ id
uid=1000(mate) gid=1000(mate) groups=1000(mate),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),132(lxd),133(sambashare)
```

The full list of tested terminals is below:

| **Terminal** | **`cat /proc/self/loginuid`** | **`logname`** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `mate-terminal` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `gnome-terminal` | 1000 | mate |
| `konsole` | 1000 | mate |
| `cool-retro-term` | 1000 | mate |
| `deepin-terminal` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| terminal in Geany | 1000 | mate |
| `guake` | 1000 | mate |
| terminal in Kate | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `kitty` | 1000 | mate |
| `lilyterm` | 1000 | mate |
| `lxterminal` | 1000 | mate |
| `mlterm` | 1000 | mate |
| `pangoterm` | 1000 | mate |
| `pterm` | 1000 | mate |
| `qterminal` | 1000 | mate |
| `rxvt` | 1000 | mate |
| `sakura` | 1000 | mate |
| `Terminal` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `terminator` | 1000 | mate |
| `terminalogy` | 1000 | mate |
| `termit` | 1000 | mate |
| `tilda` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `tilix` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `xfce4-terminal` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `xiterm+thai` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `xterm` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |
| `yakuake` | 4294967295 | `logname: no login name` |

All above terminals were installed from official Ubuntu repositories, on the same system.
But I can't understand why some work while some fail.
Some terminals are VTE based, some not. I can't find any consistent pattern here.

Comment: Disagreeing with your chart, my `gnome-terminal` also reports `cat /proc/self/loginuid` results of: `4294967295`. That said it's never been a problem. (Ubuntu 16.04 for many years)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things to note:

- 4294967295 is -1 unsigned long and means that loginuid was not set.
- The user id is set by [pam_loginuid](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_loginuid)

Uncomment `pam_loginuid` in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` and processes will pick it up too.

Comment: Running `grep pam_login /etc/pam.d/lightdm` on Ubuntu 16.04 (upgrading is on to-do list) results in `#session required        pam_loginuid.so`. I presume this is the line to uncomment? (Not that I need to because everything has been working fine for years other than a minor hic-cup here and there.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I can confirm - on 18.04 LTS gnome-terminal fails. But as for me - I think this is long standing error. So yesterday I have reported it to [launchpad](https://pav.lv/1920813) and [upstream](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/issues/183). The `pam_loginuid.so` should be uncommented as it done for systemd-user and gdm in modern (?) Ubuntu versions.